# Cocos2d: Calculate bounce of bullet when colliding with a block

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

I have a bullet that can bounce against a block. I want to find out whether the bullet bounces  in x or y direction. Like you can see on the image, only a few pixels difference let the bullet bounce it the other direction. (FYI: yes, bullets can bounce in my game ;-))

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EmGz.png]

Does anyone know a simple and solid solution for this problem?

Thanks a lot for your help

Felix

Comment: do you use Box2D or Chipmunk physics?

Comment: At the time I use no physic engine, because it should only be a tank game. Do you recommend to use one? Isn't it slower with an engine?

Comment: I'd recommend to use Box2D. Then the problem will go away because Box2D does it for you.

Comment: I tried Box2D, but I really don't want to use C++ for my App. The basic Physic is already done (in native Objective C), only this bouncing is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve the bouncing you need to make two things:

1. Collision detection
2. update position & velocity of bullet

**Step 1:**

If you want to detect collisions correctly you have to calculate the intersection of the rectangle border with a line that connects the current bullet position with the calculated next bullet position (as if there were no obstacle). If there are multiple intersection points, take the first one that hits the border. In Box2D you would use a [raycast](http://www.google.de/search?q=raycast%20box2d) to get the intersection.

That answer here will help you to determine if there are intersections: [Detect if line segment intersects square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354472/detect-if-line-segment-intersects-square/1354575#1354575)

Now you need to know at which side of the rectangle the collision occured.
The following approach assumes you already know there is a collision, but don't know where:

[image: Collision detection]

When the bullet's position is in region B, D, E or G its obvious which border will be hit.

In any other case it's not so clear. Let me explain it for region H:

1. compute the vector h (from bullet's position to lower right corner of rectangle)
2. compute the angle a out of the velocity vector v (using tangens)
3. compute the angle b out of h (using tangens)
4. compare a and b: if a < b collision is at the right side, if a > b collision is at the bottom side

Proceed similarly in case of region A, C or F.

**Step 2:**

If you have the intersection point, set the new position of the bullet to the intersection point (if you were not able to get the intersection point, update the position as if there were no obstacle, but that would be a bit inaccurate).
If the collision occured on the bottom or top, invert the y-component of the velocity.
If the collision occured on the right or left, invert the x-component of the velocity.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer. The collision detection is already finished. The only thing that's missing, is if the bullet should bounce to in x or y. You mean this code should help? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354472/detect-if-line-segment-intersects-square/1354575#1354575)