# Turning a map into a grid, then detecting if a road is in that grid?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

For a very random work project, I need to take a google map, overlay a grid, and then detect if a road passes through that grid. I can figure out the grid overlay well enough, but I'm struggling a bit on the road detection.

The closest I can think to checking this would be creating a polygon to a specific location, and then some kind of check to see if there is a road within it's bounds. I'm just not sure how I'd do that specific check. Has anyone else come across this or a similar challenge that might help?

Comment: How are you going to convert the road to a point, polyline, or similar feature that you can work with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if line segment intersects square](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354472/detect-if-line-segment-intersects-square)

Comment: I hadn't decided yet. In the past I've snapped objects to a road, by getting directions from that point to that point, and that always snapped to the closest road way, but for that to work in this instance, I'd need to check every position inside that grid, then check to see if that snapped road position is inside the bounds of the square.

This is why I was hoping there might be a better method of detection within a bounds.